# Detect emoji support in the current input method

Tags: java, android, emoji

Is it possible to detect whether the user's current keyboard supports entering emoji?

I would like to offer an alternative emoji picker, but only if the user's keyboard doesn't already support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no API for a keyboard to report what type of keys it shows or can show.